# Неправильное отображение "й" в firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, unicode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В хроме всё хорошо. Ещё на некоторых мобильных неправильно.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
В сафари она вообще замещается другим шрифтом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это отображение в хроме

Comment: Приведите пример проблемного кода.

Comment: @XelaNimed, ссылки же тут разрешены? http://blogging.fibbweb.ru/

Comment: @XelaNimed, Второй экран сверху

Comment: это сам шрифт кривой

Comment: @air, на сайте откуда скачивал в демонстрации есть нормальная "й"

Comment: Там может быть что угодно...  А у тя шрифт кривой

Comment: @Air, да не при чём тут шрифт. Текст у него кривой, а не шрифт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Как же мне мой кривой текст выпрямить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй нормальную букву `й`, а не `и` с диактитическим символом после него.

- https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/
- https://unicode-table.com/ru/0306/
- https://habr.com/post/52258/

```js
document.write("\u0439 \u0438\u0306")
```

```css
body { font-size: 8em }
```

Comment: сработало. Спасибо

Comment: Ну значит я был  не прав....

Comment: @Air, бывает - такое сложно угадать, если не знаешь :)

Comment: Даже не стану отрицать... Не сталкивался с таким...

Comment: @Air, я где-то с год или два назад читал статью, что на куче сайтов появилась буква в таком виде и где-то криво отображается, а где-то не ищется поиском.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я два  года назад, только верстать учился))))  Ну не два, может чуть больше)))

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'й' in file:
    file = file.replace('й', 'й')
elif 'ё' in file:
    file = file.replace('ё', 'ё')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь [кнопкой править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1097337/edit) и поясните, как ваш код отвечает на вопросв этом топике. Как его можно использовать для задачи ТС?